# Getting all weeks data of a month using inner join

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, join, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
select distinct 
    v.DriverName,t.KM_W1,t.KM_W2,t.KM_W3,t.KM_W4,t.KM_W5,(t.KM_W1+t.KM_W2+t.KM_W3+t.KM_W4+t.KM_W5) Total
from 
    (select 
         DriverName,
         SUM( case when TodayDate >= '01-07-2018' and TodayDate <= '07-07-2018' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W1,
         SUM( case when TodayDate >= '07-07-2018' and TodayDate <= '14-07-2018' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W2,
         SUM( case when TodayDate >= '14-07-2018' and TodayDate <= '21-07-2018' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W3,
         SUM( case when TodayDate >= '21-07-2018' and TodayDate <= '28-07-2018' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W4,
         SUM( case when TodayDate >= '28-07-2018' and TodayDate <= '31-07-2018' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W5
     from 
         Traveling
     group by 
         DriverName) t 
inner join
    Traveling v on t.DriverName = v.DriverName
where 
    TodayDate >= '01-07-2018' and TodayDate <= '31-07-2018'
```

**Above query explanation:** I'm getting all weeks data `PaidKM` which driver gets in a whole month. The month for example starting date is `01-07-2018` and ending date is `31-07-2018` which covers whole month # `07`. But when I change the month it gives me the same results all time.

[image]

**Above GIF's query implementation:** I have implemented this query in Java and when I change  the month from combo box but back end query all time gives the result from all records instead of different month.

[image]

Above image is the `Traveling` table in database.

How I can achieve the results when I change a different month? And how can I correct this query to work this?

Comment: I would start by changing the date formats to YYYY-MM-DD -- ANSI and ISO standard formats.  Does that fix your problem?

Comment: Have you tried grouping by week number with  `strftime('%W',TodayDate)`

Comment: I want to change month # instead of week #.

Comment: This would be another good use case for a Calendar Table.

Comment: For your calculated weeks, is the week number related to the month or to the year as a whole? ie is Jan 31 the last week of Jan and Feb 1 the first week of Feb, or can they both be in the same week based on the calendar year? Does each month have 4-5 weeks or does the year have 52-53 weeks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the comparisons are string based not date based. **Days** have the higher precedence than months, and months have higher precedence than years.

e.g. **31-01-1970** would be considered greater than **01-01-2018** as **31** is greater than **01**.

You should consider using a recognised date format, which is directly sortable/comparable e.g. **YYYY-MM-DD** whenever working with/storing dates.

You may wish to consider looking at [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions - **Time Strings**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

You could convert the dates to be sortable/easily compared using

```
substr(datevalue,7,4)||substr(datevalue,3,4)||substr(datevalue,1,2)
```

e.g. instead of :-

```
SUM( case when TodayDate >= '01-07-2018' and TodayDate <= '07-07-2018' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W1, ....
```

you could use :-

```
SUM( case when substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) >= '2018-07-01' and substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) <= '2018-07-07' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W1, ....
```

The whole query could be :-

```
select distinct 
    v.DriverName,t.KM_W1,t.KM_W2,t.KM_W3,t.KM_W4,t.KM_W5,(t.KM_W1+t.KM_W2+t.KM_W3+t.KM_W4+t.KM_W5) Total
from 
    (select 
         DriverName,
         SUM( case when substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) >= '2018-07-01' and substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) <= '2018-07-07' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W1,
         SUM( case when substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) >= '2018-07-08' and substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) <= '2018-07-14' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W2,
         SUM( case when substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) >= '2018-07-15' and substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) <= '2018-07-21' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W3,
         SUM( case when substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) >= '2018-07-22' and substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) <= '2018-07-28' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W4,
         SUM( case when substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) >= '2018-07-29' and substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) <= '2018-07-31' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W5
     from 
         Traveling
     group by 
         DriverName) t 
inner join
    Traveling v on t.DriverName = v.DriverName
where 
    substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) >= '2018-07-01' and substr(TodayDate,7,4)||substr(Todaydate,3,4)||substr(Todaydate,1,2) <= '2018-07-31'
```

- **Note** The above is in-principle code and has not been tested, it may therefore contain some errors.

Comment: Very nice answer thanks you saved my 50 bounty reputation .. Thanks once again.

Comment: I have just used **YYYY-MM-DD** format and it solved.

Answer (score 1):

First, two potential problems here. There are no input variables on your query, so we have to ask this first.

Did you hardcode the parameter pass-in for the `WHERE` clause at the end of statement?

Did you hardcode the parameter pass-in for the `SUM` statements in the sub-query? The ones that are splitting the month up into weeks.

These could both be the cause of the results not changing.

One for sure problem with this query is that you are going to be double counting the driving time for the days that signify the start/end of a week.

```
  ...SUM( case when TodayDate >= '01-07-2018' and TodayDate <= '07-07-2018' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W1,
    SUM( case when TodayDate >= '08-07-2018' and TodayDate <= '14-07-2018' then PaidKM else 0 end) KM_W2,...
```

You'll need to increment the days before the start of the next week
I've done so here by updating `07-07-2018` to `08-07-2018`

Comment: the answer to your questions is no. then the I changed the date as you described but still same results.

Comment: the overlapping dates were a separate issues from your original question. It was just an error that would have to be fixed before this report would behave how you want it to.